# How to parse below JSON

Tags: javascript, json

How to parse below JSON code in JavaScript where iterators are not identical?

```
var js= { 
    '7413_7765': { 
        availableColorIds: [ '100', '200' ],
        listPrice: '$69.00',
        marketingMessage: '',
        prdId: '7413_7765',
        prdName: 'DV by Dolce Vita Archer Sandal',
        rating: 0,
        salePrice: '$59.99',
        styleId: '7765' 
    },
    '0417_2898': { 
        availableColorIds: [ '249', '203' ],
        listPrice: '$24.95',
        marketingMessage: '',
        prdId: '0417_2898',
        prdName: 'AEO Embossed Flip-Flop',
        rating: 4.5,
        salePrice: '$19.99',
        styleId: '2898' 
    },
    prod6169041: { 
        availableColorIds: [ '001', '013', '800' ],
        listPrice: '$89.95',
        marketingMessage: '',
        prdId: 'prod6169041',
        prdName: 'Birkenstock Gizeh Sandal',
        rating: 5,
        salePrice: '$79.99',
        styleId: '7730' 
    } 
}
```

How can I parse this JSON in JavaScript? I want the values of `prdName`, `listprice`, `salePrice` in JavaScript?

Comment: That's not JSON... It's already JavaScript.

Comment: @user2244199 can you post the JSON alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var products = js; // more semantic
for (productId in products){
   var product = products[productId];
   console.log (product.prdName , product.listprice, product.salePrice);
}
```

js is an Object, the `for (key in instance)` iteration moves through the first level object's attributes, in this case  7413_7765, 0417_2898 and prod6169041, this keys are stored in the `var productId`, so `products[productId]` will return the value of this attributes.

Note that the "" in object keynames are not necesary.

Comment: using this, how would you get '0417_2898', prod6169041, and '7413_7765' ?

Comment: I tried with above but getting undefined. Ho w i will get  '0417_2898', prod6169041, and '7413_7765'

Comment: js is a JS Object, the for (product in object) iterator moves through the first level attributes, in this case  7413_7765, 0417_2898 and prod6169041, this keys are stored in the var productId, js[productId] will return the value of this attributes,

Comment: Glad to help @user2244199, it gived me so much headaches time ago.

Answer (score 0):

You have already assigned the JSON to an object `js`.

You're trying to **loop through JavaScript object**, as Edorka mentioned iterate it.